# insert data into database for shopping cart

Tags: php, shopping-cart, sql-insert

I am doing a shopping cart and I am not sure where or rather which page do I code my INSERT INTO statement.

viewProducts.php

```
 <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['cartCity'])) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM productsc WHERE id_product IN (";
                foreach ($_SESSION['cartCity'] as $id => $value) {
                    $sql .= $id . ",";
                }
                $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ") ORDER BY id_product ASC";
                $query = mysql_query($sql);
                if (!empty($query)) {
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        ?>
                        <p><?php echo $row['name']; ?><?php echo " x " . $_SESSION['cartCity'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']; ?></p>

                        <?php
                    }
                   } else {
                    echo "<i>You need to add an item to your cart for it to be visible here</i><br />";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p>Your cart is empty. <br/> Please add some products</p>";
            }
            echo "<a href='viewProductsCity.php?page=cartCity'>Go to Cart</a>";
            echo "<a href='checkout.php'>Checkout</a>";
            ?>
```

or should i add in cart or viewAdd(this is where the codes for when the customer clicks on add to cart button runs) page?

Comment: A little off topic, but your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: instead of struggling with boilerplate generic php code, why not pickup a library like http://codeigniter.com ? It has an integrated shopping cart feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate page to do that.

Then, I would include it just by redirecting the user there or by calling it with AJAX. When user got the cart with something, then yeah, we would redirect him to the checkout, and ask him if he wants to buy now or keep shopping.

Comment: do you mind giving an example on how do i go about doing this? thanks(: @Ivo Pereira